# web matrix and orchard cms editing the "Add Widget" Page

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms, webmatrix

I am very new to the use of Orchard. I installed Web Matrix 3 and added Orchard CMS to it.
My question is : 
On the admin Page from which i got access to everything on the new orchard cms site, i go to "widgets" and try to add a new "Html Widget".
it redirects me to an "Add Widget" page with input boxes for title, date and other things, and also an text editor in which i can put anything i want. 
I want to be able to put an image there and then be able to drag it around the editor container...so when i save this widget the image will stay on the position that i dragged it to inside the editor.
How and / or Where can i do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what editor you use for the HTML body. Default it uses the TinyMCE editor, which provides an 'Add image' button to insert an image:

[image: TinyMCE insert image]

When you click this button you can insert an image from the image gallery of your Orchard Media section.